# Unable to Bootstrap node using Chef

Tags: chef-solo, chef-infra

I've set up a basic Chef infrastructure that contains a workstation, a hosted Chef Server and an Ubuntu Server to serve as a node. I'm using this setup at my workplace and therefore a proxy is required for internet connections. I've made the necessary proxy settings in both `knife.rb` and the Ubuntu Server. Both the workstation and the node are properly connected to the internet.
Here's the problem - When I try to bootstrap this node using `knife`, I get the following error:

```
<My Node's IP> --2014-02-12 10:29:05--  https://www.opscode.com/chef/install.sh
<My Node's IP> Resolving www.opscode.com (www.opscode.com)... 184.106.28.91
<My Node's IP> Connecting to www.opscode.com (www.opscode.com)|184.106.28.91|:443... failed: Connection refused.
<My Node's IP> bash: line 83: chef-client: command not found
```

Please note that I used the following command to bootstrap the node -

```
knife bootstrap <My Node's IP> --sudo -x <username> -P <password> -N <name>
```

Can you please help me with this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After struggling on this for a long time I have finally found the answer.
In `knife.rb` another entry for bootstrap-proxy has to made as well.

```
knife[:bootstrap_proxy] = "http://username:password@proxy:port"
```

After doing this, run the following bootstrap command -

```
knife bootstrap <My Node's IP> --sudo -x <username> -P <password> -N <name>
```

This worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered the same problem. You just need to type the same thing with some extra commands:

```
knife bootstrap <My Node's IP> --sudo -x <username> -P <password> -N <name> --bootstrap-wget-options --no-check-certificate
```

It will work always.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I didn't added the server in client's hosts file entry. for example,
I got this error "Connection refused - Connection refused connecting to https://server.com/organizations/sample/nodes/node1"
I simple made an entry in "/etc/hosts" file with my server's IP and name i.e "server.com" and it worked for me.

## vi /etc/hosts

192.168.159.100 server.com